# make: *** No rule to make target 'unistall'. Stop

Tags: make

I am trying to uninstall a package from source code.

When I tried this command

```
sudo make unistall
```

I got this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'unistall'.  Stop
```

Comment: That looks like a simple typo: unistall should be uni**n**stall?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, thank you, its working :) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem or error arises from the word `unistall`. It should be a simple typo as @steeldriver commented.  So instead you should run the command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

And you won't get the error anymore.